# Unable to access local PHP Class?

Tags: php

I have been trying to test how it is possible to run functions of a local, external PHP class file and I have had no luck with it at all.

I have two classes;

```
<?php

Class Conversion {

public function convert () {
    return "HI!";
}

}

?>
```

And:

```
<?php
class Config {
}

$t = new Conversion();
echo $t->convert();

?>
```

Both of these files are in the same directory when I test them and yet I can never get an output when using the `Config` class, why is this? When I instantiate and echo the `Conversion` class within the Conversion.php file it works fine, but I can't get it to work when doing the same in the Config.php file - why is this?

Comment: did you `include` or `require` the files?

Comment: You have done `include('Conversion.php);` inside `Config.php`? And you have `display_errors` turned on?

Comment: Use the PHP 5 __autoload function, add it early inside your application and define the function accordingly. This will solve many issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having them in the same directory isn't going to do anything. You have to include one in the other to use it's code.

```
include('path/to/file.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save the `Conversion` class as Conversion.class.php and `Config` in Config.class.php (name them as you like - this is just my suggestion), then to use them in a script (assuming they are all in the same folder together you just need this:

```
include("Conversion.class.php");
include("Config.class.php");

$config_example = new Config;
```

Comment: It's ok to leave the parenthesis.  It's just not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't remember for sure... I guess it's the constructor member that you're calling, and you need the parenthesis if there are any parameter to pass.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the `Conversion` class file in your `Config`.

```
<?php
include('Conversion_file.php');
class Config {
}

$t = new Conversion();
echo $t->convert();

?>
```

or use autoload in the file that is calling your classes (like config.php in your case)

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}
```

for info about [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)